# License "Developer for IBM Enterprise Platforms"

Tags: rtc, rational-team-concert

I saw that our installation of RTC contains a 60 day trial of a license called "Developer for IBM Enterprise Platforms". Info about the license is;

> The Developer for IBM Enterprise Platforms license is designed for professional developers actively participating in the project. In addition to the capabilities provided by the Developer license,  this license adds advanced building with dependency management, build impact analysis, promotion support (z/OS), deployment support (z/OS, IBM i, UNIX, and Linux) and advanced context aware search. It is designed for development teams targeting System z and Power Systems platforms.

Question is, does this license add something useful if we do no work at all in IBM plattforms?

Comment: Read the last sentence you quoted. Are you "targeting System z and Power System platforms"? If not, then it says it's adding nothing useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the last sentence reference IBM platforms, we (large organization) are using those licenses for Windows and Unix development.

What is interesting is the "advanced building with dependency management, build impact analysis,  deployment support (z/OS, IBM i, UNIX, and Linux) and advanced context aware search."

So yes, you can use those licenses outside of IBM platforms.

We also have simple "Developers" licenses, as presented in "[Licensing in the Rational solution for Collaborative Lifecycle Management (CLM) 2012](https://jazz.net/library/article/825/)".